# Can't boot to newly created Recovery Partiton

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery-hd

I am using DeployStudio to distribute my Mac images and when I create a new image the recovery partiton seems to be deleted on the new Retinas.  I have followed this in the past, http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/removing-and-rebuilding-a-malfunctioning-recover-hd-partition/, and it worked fine on older models.  On the Retinas it will create the partition but not let me boot to it.  I get the "no" symbol.

Answer (score 1):

That process seems to install a 10.7.2 version of the recovery partition. The Retina MBPs were released with a [special build of 10.7.4](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-os-x-ios-windows-support.html), so they won't be able to boot off a recovery partition based on the earlier version.

To get a working partition for the rMBPs, try using these [instructions](http://www.brunerd.com/blog/2012/03/21/update-create-lion-recoveryhd-partition-quickly-without-reinstalling/) with the 10.7.5 (or 10.8.x) installer. Alternatively, if you want to stay on 10.7.4, you could do a clean restore from Internet Recovery on one of the rMBPs to get the default restore partition back, and use that as a source to clone to the others.

Comment: Would internet recovery not result in the latest release being downloaded? I always thought the only way to have a reinstall of old versions was to have one lying around.